# Getting Images in the form of Grid in AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, css, angular-ui-bootstrap

How to display all the images in the form of grid, which all will come from back end, so the images are in the dynamic form. and I have to put Description as well on those images, and those Description are also coming from Back End in AngularJS?

Comment: Can you give example of what you have tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If image data is coming in array then you can show image using **ng-repeat** directive.

**Controller**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.imageList = allImage;
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-3" ng-repeat="image in imageList track by $index">
    <img src="{{image.imageUrl}}" />
    <label> {{image.description}} </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ng-repeat` for showing you image with description like:

```
<li class="col-sm-3" ng-repeat="product in productList">
                        <img src={{product.imageUrl}} />
                        <label>{{product.description}}</label>
                    </li>
```

[Here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) is the documentation